# On the extension of Euler's identity in 3 dimensions

Tags: trigonometry

Is there an extension for Euler's identity $e^{i\theta}=-1$ for 3 dimensions, expressed in terms of $\theta$ and $\phi$ ?
The formula above can only be used in 2 dimensions, and can only be expressed in terms of $\theta$.

Comment: Euler's identity is $e^{i\pi} = -1$, and has no variables, so what exactly is your question?

Comment: Euler's identity is a set of constants $e^{i\pi}=-1$ there are no variables in it. If you are talking about Euler's formula $e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i\sin\theta$ you could always parameterize $\theta$ as the sum of two other variables

Comment: If you are talking about the fact that Euler's identity is a fact about complex analysis, and $C$ is a 2 dimensional space, there is a 4 dimensional complex space known as the quaternions, and this post talks about an extension to Euler's formula for quaternions https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41574/can-eulers-identity-be-extended-to-quaternions

Comment: Euler's formula type identities work for division algebras. Since there is no 3 dimensional division algebra there can be no "3D Euler's identity". As remarked by Jacob Raymond the closest you can get is a 4D version using quaternions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really mean is $r\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\theta} = r\cos \theta + r \mathrm i \sin \theta$.

Hint: This is derived from Taylor series. If polar coordinates use $r$ and $\theta$, then how could you extend this to [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system)?